# TextBox events auto firing when tab, key up-down or scrolling the list view WINRT (Windows 10 app)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

We have created a window 10 app using WinRT C# app, where we have a listview to show controls like textbox and textblock in each row, on the textbox TextChanged,  GotFocus and LostFocus etc. events are added. When user enter value in qty textbox the sell is calculated and shown in sell textboxes. Below is the code sample -

[image: Code Sample]

[image: App UI]

The problem is that when we enter value in textbox and keep pressing tab, UP-Down key or scroll the listview same values (qty and sell) has appears on the different rows and continuously increased, which creating huge problem.

Comment: Post code **always** as text. Please update your question

Comment: I do not think anyone will be willing to help u. Because you post your code as an image. No one wants to code manually by your screenshot. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake to forget that `tab` is a key and fires the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events just like hitting the `q` or `w` key would. My guess is you need something like this:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid(e.Key))
    {
        MyLogic();
    }
}

private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid(e.Key))
    {
        MyLogic();
    }
}

private bool IsValid(VirtualKey key)
{
    return key != VirtualKey.Tab;
}

void MyLogic()
{
    // TODO
}
```

Best of luck.